# Регулярка php preg_match table + class

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, требуется помощь в написание регулярки для **PHP** `preg_match`, нужно вытащить весь текст вместе с тегами (`<table>`), которые имеют определенный класс (`class="test"`), который в свое время может находится в любой очередности возможных атрибутов.

Например

```
<table class="test">
   <tr>
      <td>bla bla bla</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

или

```
<table border="1" class="test">
   <tr>
      <td>bla bla bla</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

или

```
<table border="1" style="color:#bb0011" class="test">
   <tr>
      <td>bla bla bla</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Может ли в исходную таблицу быть вложена другая таблица?

Comment: Здравствуйте, нет, не может...

Answer (score 2):

```
/<table\b[^>]*?\bclass\s*=\s*(['"]).*?\btest\b.*?\1.+?<\/table>/si
```

Что ищем

- `<table` - последовательность `<table`
- `\b` - конец слова. `<tablerow` нам не подходит
- `[^>]*?` - любые символы, кроме `>` в любом количестве, но не жадно
- `\bclass` - слово, начинающееся с `class`
- `\s*=\s*` - знак `=`, обрамленный 0 или больше пробелов
- `(['"])` - одинарная или двойная кавычка
- `.*?` - любые символы в любом количестве
- `\btest\b` - отдельное слово `test`
- `.*?` - любые символы в любом количестве
- `\1` - именно та кавычка, которая нам встретилась до этого
- `.+?` - любые символы в количестве одного или больше
- `<\/table>` - закрывающий тег
- `/si` - не учитывать переводы строк, регистр не учитывать

Comment: Спасибо, но выдает ошибку... preg_match_all('<table\b.*?\bclass\s*=\s*([\'"]).*?\btest\b.*?\1.+?<\/table>', $html, $match); Warning: preg_match_all(): No ending matching delimiter '>' found in

Comment: ну дык блин, в preg_*** регулярку надо обрамлять в // и указывать флаги...  `'/regexp/ui'`, где regexp - собственно регулярка.   u - поиск с учетом юникодов, i - нечувствительно к регистру (заглавные/строчные)

Comment: Нерабочие примеры вашей регулярки ;) https://regex101.com/r/Dmxxox/1 https://regex101.com/r/Dmxxox/2

Comment: @Visman а флаги кто будет ставить? https://regex101.com/r/Dmxxox/3

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, так взял ваш ответ, как он представлен. И второй пример неверной обработки от флагов не зависит.

Comment: @Visman Поправил

Answer (score 1):

Прошу прощения, может не в тему, а если использовать `DOMDocument`?

```
$html = "Ваш html код";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query("//table[@class=\"test\"]");

foreach ($result as $table)
{
    echo $dom->saveHTML($table);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант, а как в таком случае заменить найденный текст html кодом?

Comment: @SergeyLipuringa не много не понял, чего вы хотите ) "заменить найденный текст html кодом" можно не много подробнее? я так понял: вы хотите заменить найденный `table` другим содержимым в `$html`, так?

Comment: Решение отличное! Только при помощи `contains` Вы найдете и такое `<table class="test123">`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov согласен, поправил

Comment: Необходимо вытащить кусок кода из html, далее обработать его, и вернуть на тоже место...

Comment: в общем, как раз все можно сделать с использованием `DOMDocument`, в цикле как все изменишь нужно в конце сделать `$table->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $table);` , `$newNode` это как раз ты меняешь что надо, и затем из измененного контента создаешь новый элемент через `$dom->createElement` , почитай об этом в инете

Comment: То, что Вы поправили, не факт, что стало лучше. HTML позволяет указывать несколько классов через пробел `<table class="test test1 test2">`- Наверное должно быть как-то так `"//table[@class='test' or starts-with(@class, 'test ') or ends-with(@class, ' test') or contains(@class, ' test ')]"`. И то при условии предварительной замены всех пробельных символов пробелами

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, спасибо, учту